# Phonegap Build CLI 6.3.0 with com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect 0.9.0

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

Get an error If I try to build my App with `Phonegap Build CLI 6.3.0`:

> "Error - The following 3rd-party plugin is causing the build to fail
>   and may need to be updated to a newer version:
>   com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect"

But version="0.9.0" is the latest version.
Have someone a solution for this problem?

**config.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="" 
version="1.1.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

    <name></name>
    <description></description>
    <author email="" href="http://www.lions-media.at/">Lions Media</author>

    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />

    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />

  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />



  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />

  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>

  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>

  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
  </platform>

  <icon src="resources/icon.png"/>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-extension" spec="1.5.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="pgb" spec="3.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="pgb" spec="1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="pgb" spec="1.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="1.0.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="pgb" spec="1.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="pgb" spec="2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.0" />
<plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" spec="5.1.3" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" spec="2.3.0" />

<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="" />
</gap:plugin>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion">
        <string>de_DE</string>
    </gap:config-file>


  <plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git"/>
</widget>
```